# Fast way to add column of workdays between date range (Excel-VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I will like to create a table with a column that contains the dates of all weekdays within a date range. I've implemented some code in excel-vba (that works) that looks like this:

## Main

```
Sub columnofworkdaystest()

'init
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("A2").Value = "Date"

'Set the table
ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A2:A4"), , xlYes).Name = "table1"
Dim hcrtbl As ListObject
Set hcrtbl = ws.ListObjects("table1")

'get dates
Dim startdate, enddate, runningdate As Date
startdate = Date - 20
enddate = Date
runningdate = startdate

'insert rows - this part is really slow
ws.Range("A2").Offset(1, 0).Value = runningdate
Do While runningdate <= enddate
    hcrtbl.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange(hcrtbl.ListRows.Count - 1, 1).Value = runningdate
    hcrtbl.ListRows.Add
    runningdate = GetNextWorkDay(runningdate)
Loop

End Sub
```

## GetNextWorkDay

```
'I copied this from here: http://www.nullskull.com/q/10252552/find-next-working-day-vba.aspx
Function GetNextWorkDay(dtTemp As Date)
    GetNextWorkDay = dtTemp + IIf(Weekday(dtTemp) > 5, 9 - Weekday(dtTemp), 1)
End Function
```

The current do-while loop is way too slow if I will like to get a date range of over a few months. Is there some way I can amend this to make it work faster?

Comment: The current loop takes 0.06 seconds for me.  (0.4 seconds to insert a year.)  How fast does it need to be?

Comment: Hi @YowE3K, thank you for your reply. I just found out that I get about the same performance with an empty workbook, but it takes about 0.3s per insert for the workbook I'm working on (which has alot of data in other places). Any ideas why that may be so?

Comment: @jsotola dude you are the man! Will you like to post an answer in the space below so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a huge worksheet ... turn off auto recalc